# Using Android card view leads to crash of the app

Tags: java, android, cardview

I try to integrate a card view in my layout, but the app crashes with following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

This is the layout xml that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backdrop_rounded_front"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:text="Category: All"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:textAllCaps="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:text="Empty question"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        />


    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Empty "
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E4F4FF"
        android:divider="@null"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I added the dependency for the cardview, but the dependency is red underlined. As suggestion it says to migrate to android x. If I do so, nothing happens.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.roiacult:BackdropLayout:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

I am using Android Studio 3.5
Compile SDK Version: 29
Build Tool Version: 29.0.1
Min SDK version: 19
Using Java code

Thank you! (:

Answer (score 2):

You were migrate to androidx but keep using support lib for CardView. Change this import in dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Also change root in XML file

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Empty "
            />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: OP still has to change the `CardView` XML tag though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `AndroidX` library with `support` library. 
In your module level `build.gradle` remove

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

And in your layout try to use

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Comment: @Bejanka, Have you checked this?